# Filepond : manually revert to default image

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am trying to reset a *filepond field* to a *default image* on user action (ie: clicking on a button).
The file could be local or uploaded somewhere (as AWS) it does not matter.
I currently load a default image when the webpage (and therefore the filepond instance / element) is first loaded, so I guess manually calling the `load` method would do the trick but I can't manage to do that.
I also try with the `file-poster` plugin, but there is no way to reset the image after it has been deleted.

If you have found a way of doing this or are thinking about something, please let me know :)

Comment: You can use `removeFile` to remove the existing file and then run `addFile` to add a new (default) file?

Comment: No, because `addFile` will cause the file to be uploaded on the server and this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @Rik was right, just use `addFile` function with the option `type: "local"`.